# Virtual router not working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, hp-pavilion

I have tried installing Virtual router in my laptop having Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter. But it shows Error: `group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.` I tried sharing LAN or WiFi both but for both result is same. I also tried Hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496820.

Comment: Your Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter may not be working. Try this in an elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator): `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow`

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.
please go **Device Manager**>>**Network adapters**

see if there is any disabled device(forgot to read the name) shown here go to **Properties** and enable it.

this solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before and was solved like this:

1. Go to control panel => Network and INTERNET => Network and sharing center => change adapter settings
2. Right click on Wireless network collection if it is already enabled disable it and enable it again
3. Right click after it is enabled and choose status
4. Click properties => sharing => check the box => choose wireless private network

Answer (score -1):

Your Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter may not be working. Try this in an elevated command prompt (Run as Administrator): netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow

you can have solution here also...[click here](http://TheWeeklyJob.com/?id=26840)

Comment: post the answer here, not an external link